# Map in a form submits when zooming

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have a map as part of a form (users move the map to submit a location).
When you build a form in our CMS, it wraps everything in the form tag, including the map - pretty common, really.

When a user clicks one of the map controls to zoom in or out, it submits the form. Not optimal!

Example here: https://output.jsbin.com/mejidew/

Yes, I probably can work out a way of getting the map div outside the form tag, but it means refactoring my form quite significantly. I'd like to avoid this if possible - after all, it seems like a bug to me that the zoom function allows the click action to pass through to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the bug report! Fix coming in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/2935!

Comment: Yay! Thanks, Lucas :-)